# BDCM for small DIY overhead stirrer, how to choose based on Kv?

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor, diy

I want to make a DIY overhead stirrer, to stir a glass of 5 Litres of pure water to bewtween 100-2000 rpm using a common impeller. I want to use a brushless DC motor (BLDC) to drive the impeller. After some calculations, and some research from [commercial stirrers which also use BLDCs](https://www.caframolabsolutions.com/products/overhead-stirrers/petite-250/), I found that I need one with an output power of about **15 watts** (which will be connected to an appropriate power supply, itself connected to the wall outlet of the house: 220 V, 50 Hz). The torque could be around **20 N.cm** if I'm not mistaken.

After browsing, most BLDC offers seem to be for the RC hobby, and the motors are rated by a "Kv" unit (rpm/volt). I tried searching for a way to convert Kv to Watts, but couldn't find one. I simply want to buy one of these BLDCs that will be appropiate for my apparatus, but I can't seem to get that from the Kv value.

Can someone suggest me a way to decide which Kv rate of BLDC is appropiate for my apparatus?

Comment: "BDCM"? What a weird acronym. What is wrong with BLDC?

Comment: Since the KV rating is in units of rpm/volt, I would presume it is indicating how the speed varies with applied voltage.  You would need to look at the available range of output voltages from your power supply in comparison to the speed range you need for your application (100-200 rpm).  [It is probably more complicated than this, but based on the dimensional analysis, the answer is in this direction.]

Comment: @Maple my bad, edited it

Comment: @JuanPerez I am trying to build an overhead stirrer as well. Would be happy to exchange ideas, if you like.